# Does one party involved in the action of "introducing someone to someone else" have a higher authority?

Tags: politeness

When you use the sentences such as "Kate introduced Joe to Ellen", "My former colleague introduced me to his boss", "My brother introduced them to me", is there one side of the introduction that has a higher authority or level of respect than the other?

For example, is Ellen in the first sentence at the "upper" position with respect to Joe? Or when I say "My brother introduced them to me", does it mean I'm assuming a higher authority for myself (for instance, I'll be the boss and those introduced my employees)?

Comment: It just depends on what Kate says first.  Does she say one of these: [1. "Joe, I'd like to introduce you to Ellen.  Ellen, this is Joe.", 2. "Joe, this is Ellen.  Ellen,  Joe." 3. "Joe, I'd like you to meet Ellen. Ellen, This is Joe."]  **or** one of these: 
 [4. "Ellen, I'd like to introduce you to Joe.  Joe, this is Ellen.", 5. "Ellen, this is Joe.  Joe,  Ellen." 6. "Ellen, I'd like you to meet Joe. Joe, this is Ellen."]  In the first set (1-3) you are introducing Ellen to Joe.  In the second (4-6), Joe to Ellen.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about English but about etiquette. Try SE: Interpersonal or SE: Workplace.

Comment: Yes, I believe so. However, this is a question of etiquette, not language, as already noted by @Knotell Maybe [workplace.se] or [interpersonal.se]

Comment: @Knotell I disagree. This is about the language used. It's asking about the nuance of who is introduced to whom. It's not about what you should do to show respect, it's about how respect is being communicated *by the sentence*.

Comment: In a word, no.  There are of course, reasons why one person is more likely to know the people involved and be in a situation to introduce them, but there's no general rule you can apply.

Answer (score 2):

There may be somewhat higher of authority being given to the person after "to". When we "introduce A to B", it sounds like one thing is being taken to meet a fixed thing. For example, in chemistry, you might "introduce some acid into the water". The water is fixed, the acid is being brought to the water.

For people, the same rule follows. So person B is the person who "belongs" in the place, who is "fixed". In many cases, this is because person B is in a higher status of authority, whether that's actual authority, or simply being more senior in the place you're currently in. For example, maybe you're introducing a friend to your boss, introducing your girlfriend to your parents, or introducing your father to your friends (in your usual place for hanging out).

However, it wouldn't be too unusual to reverse these, especially if you are talking directly to someone. For example, "Oh, I'd like to introduce you to my friend."

So in summary, there is a *slight* sense of authority in person B (in "introduce A to B"), but it's not something speakers or listeners will actually think about, and so there's no risk of accidentally causing offense if, for example, you introduce your boss to your friend.

Answer (score 1):

"Introduce" as a word describing what happens is now neutral in a way that the word "present" in the identical context is not: "my former colleague presented me to his boss" leaves no room for doubt as to who is the superior person. But you could equally well say "my former colleague introduced me to his junior staff".

When we next visit Buckingham Palace I shall present you to Her Majesty, but the Queen might well say afterwards that she had been introduced to you.

It may be that some lingering memory of old-fashioned etiquette guides  - "you should introduce the younger man to the older" - had led to the OP's question, but that is all gone now.